# OWASP ZAP says that httponly flag is missing, but it presents in chrome. Any ideas how to fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, cookies, owasp, cookie-httponly

I'm using owasp zap to check my rails (v. 5.0.2) application security. There where a bunch of issues with cookies like 'Cookie No HttpOnly Flag', 'Cookie Without SameSite Attribute', 'Cookie Without Secure Flag'. I've monkeypatch this with help of this code (which was taken from one of suggestions in rails repository)

```
module CookieJarExtensions
  def handle_options(options)
    super

    options[:httponly] = true
    options[:same_site] = :lax
    options[:secure] = true
  end
end

ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar.class_eval do
  prepend CookieJarExtensions
end
```

And when i'm looking in browser it works (at least chrome cookies said that 'Accessible to script No (HttpOnly)') but owasp still says that it's available for javascript. And yes, i'm pretty sure that it's the same cookies. Any ideas why it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look the HTTP response associated with the alert - can you see the flag?